# Why won't fancontrol start on boot, but will start with sudo?

Tags: 12.04, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I've configured /etc/fancontrol to my liking

```
# Configuration file generated by pwmconfig, changes will be lost
INTERVAL=10
DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/it87.552
DEVNAME=hwmon0=it8718
FCTEMPS=hwmon0/device/pwm2=hwmon0/device/temp2_input hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon0/device/pwm2=hwmon0/device/fan2_input hwmon0/device/pwm1=hwmon0/device/fan1_input
MINTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm2=20 hwmon0/device/pwm1=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon0/device/pwm2=60 hwmon0/device/pwm1=60
MINSTART=hwmon0/device/pwm2=150 hwmon0/device/pwm1=150
MINSTOP=hwmon0/device/pwm2=100 hwmon0/device/pwm1=100
MAXPWM=hwmon0/device/pwm2=225 hwmon0/device/pwm1=225
```

`sudo fancontrol` works perfectly.

But it won't start on boot.

**UPDATE**

OK, I think I've found the problem.

In /etc/init.d there is a file called:

```
james@middlepc:/etc/init.d$ ls fan*
fancontrol.dpkg-bak
```

If I run `sudo /etc/init.d/fancontrol.dpkg-bak start` the fan controller starts.

**Should this be `fancontrol`? Is this evidence of a corrupted installation?**

**UPDATE 2**

I've tried renaming `fancontrol.dpkg-bak` to `fancontrol`.
It still doesn't start on boot

**Rest of original post**

If I run `fancontrol` without `sudo` I get the following output:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...

Common settings:
  INTERVAL=10

Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm2:
  Depends on hwmon0/device/temp2_input
  Controls hwmon0/device/fan2_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=100
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=225

Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm1:
  Depends on hwmon0/device/temp1_input
  Controls hwmon0/device/fan1_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=100
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=225

Error: file hwmon0/device/pwm2 doesn't exist
Error: file hwmon0/device/pwm1 doesn't exist

At least one referenced file is missing. Either some required kernel
modules haven't been loaded, or your configuration file is outdated.
In the latter case, you should run pwmconfig again.
```

I tried changing `DEVPATH=hwmon0=devices/platform/it87.552` to `DEVPATH=hwmon0=/sys/devices/platform/it87.552` but that just produces:

```
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...

Common settings:
  INTERVAL=10

Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm2:
  Depends on hwmon0/device/temp2_input
  Controls hwmon0/device/fan2_input:
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=100
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=225

Settings for hwmon0/device/pwm1:
  Depends on hwmon0/device/temp1_input
  Controls hwmon0/device/fan1_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=100
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=225

Device path of hwmon0 has changed
Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again
```

If I run `sudo find / | grep it87.552` I get:

```
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/uevent
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/modalias
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/subsystem
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/async
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_status
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_usage
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_active_kids
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_enabled
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/control
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_suspended_time
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/runtime_active_time
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/driver
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in0_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in1_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in2_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in4_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in5_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in6_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in7_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in8_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in0_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in1_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in2_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in4_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in5_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in6_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in7_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in0_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in1_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in2_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in4_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in5_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in6_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in7_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in0_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in1_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in2_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in4_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in5_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in6_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in7_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_max
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_type
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_type
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_type
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/alarms
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/intrusion0_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/name
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in0_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in1_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in2_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in4_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in5_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in6_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in7_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp1_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp2_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/temp3_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan1_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan1_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan1_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan1_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan2_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan2_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan2_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan2_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan3_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan3_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan3_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan3_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan4_input
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan4_min
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan4_alarm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/fan4_beep
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm1_enable
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm1
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm1_freq
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm1_auto_channels_temp
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm2_enable
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm2
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm2_freq
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm2_auto_channels_temp
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm3_enable
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm3
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm3_freq
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/pwm3_auto_channels_temp
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/vrm
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/cpu0_vid
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in3_label
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/in8_label
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/uevent
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/subsystem
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/device
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/async
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_status
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_usage
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_active_kids
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_enabled
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/control
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_suspended_time
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/runtime_active_time
/sys/devices/platform/it87.552/hwmon/hwmon0/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
/sys/bus/platform/devices/it87.552
/sys/bus/platform/drivers/it87/it87.552
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you've fixed it yourself - if the problem were broken rc.d links, you could have tried

```
sudo update-rc.d fancontrol defaults
```

Comment: Yes, but ticking my own answer just feels like cheating...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The installation was corrupt.

The startup script was named some part-installed backup name and I guess the rc.d links were busted because it too this to get it working again:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install fancontrol`